# Intellisense not working for CMake CUDA project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda, intellisense

I have a very simple CUDA project:

- a [single .cu file](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).
- a simple CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(simpleCuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(simpleCuda)

target_sources(simpleCuda PUBLIC main.cu)

target_compile_features(simpleCuda PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

I can open that folder and build/run the executable just fine. However, all the CUDA intellisense is messed up (`__global__`, `cudaMalloc`, etc.). Am I missing something? See my `CMakeSettings.json` below

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [],
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the CMake target view:

[image]

Note that the intellisense for C++ is also messed up. I don't get any auto-completetion.

Comment: Have you tried creating a normal Visual Studio project?

Comment: If I do that, it won't use CMake at all, no?

Comment: This question should be raised to Microsoft as its a very expensive proprietary software and should support it. BTW we are using VS 2019 CMake projects which are build on Linux. intelligence never worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Intellisense not working for CMake CUDA project in Visual Studio 2019

I think you should use add `include_directories("xxxx"//contain the CUDA library path)` in `CMakeLists.txt` file to include **CUDA** library for Intellisense.

Add this in every `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
include_directories("C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include")
```

**Besides**, if it still does not work, please these steps:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder and any output folders like `out` and then restart your project to test again.

**2)** disable any other third party vs extensions under **Extensions** menu-->**Manage Extensions** to check whether it is caused by some extensions.

**3)** reset all vs settings by **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**->**Reset All settings**

**4)** [do a repair in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version

Comment: VS does not support "modern" CMake targets? Technically, these include directories are known by CMake when I do the `find_package` and `target_link_libraries`. I will try the other steps though to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, can restart the project succeed? It is quite strange that your intellisense will mess up. So please try the following steps to check whether it helps or not.